# How to test React custom hook that uses a context?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I need to wrap my custom hook in a TaskContext in order for my tests to pass. Currently they fail with  "Cannot read property 'taskState' of undefined" taskState represents the state object within the TaskContext. I have tried wrapping my hook in the code below but my test still fails.

My custom hook is called useProtocolEdit. I use another hook called mountHook to for testing it. All tests were passing before I added the TaskContext.

```
  it("edit question", () => {
   let setupComponent = mountHook(useProtocolEdit)
   let hook = setupComponent.componentHook;
   let currentProtocol = {name: 'one'}
   let protocolId = 'some id'
   hook.editState.currentProtocol = currentProtocol

   act(() => {
     return (
       <TaskContext.Provider value={{ taskState: {tasks: null} }}>
         {hook.editActions.editProtocol(currentProtocol, protocolId)}
       </TaskContext.Provider>
     )
   })
   expect(hook.editState.isEdit).toBe(true)
   expect(hook.editState.protocolId).toBe('some id')
   expect(hook.editState.currentProtocol).toBe(currentProtocol)
 })
```

My custom hook code

```
  const useProtocolEdit = () => {
    const [editState, setEditState] = useState(INITIAL_STATE)
    const {index, protocolId, currentProtocol} = editState
    const {taskActions} = useTask()  

 const editProtocol = (currentProtocol, protocolId) => {
   setEditState({
     ...editState,
     isEdit: true,
    protocolId: protocolId,
    currentProtocol: currentProtocol
   })
 }

 const updateProtocol = (body, file = null) => {
   let updateProtocol = currentProtocol
   let updatedAnswers = updateProtocol.answeredQuestions
       updatedAnswers.splice(index, 1, ...body.answeredQuestions)

   body._id = protocolId
   body.answeredQuestions = updatedAnswers

   protocolService.update(body).then(res => {
     if (file) {
       protocolPhoto(res, file)
     }

     else {  
       taskActions.replaceTask(res)
       close()
     }
   })
 }

 const editActions = {
   editProtocol
 }

 return {editState, editActions}
```

}

useTask is what I use to call a function within taskActions

Comment: Can you show an example how you use the hook within a component, and how exactly it depends on the context?

Comment: I have edited my question to show the code from my hook. For the test in my example I'm not even calling the taskActions.replaceTask() function from my TaskContext. When the hook mounts it is looking for the TaskContext and returning undefined for taskState.

Comment: Seems to me you try to consume the context object from inside the custom hook, but hooks are not part of the component tree. Instead, consume the context in a component that is wrapped by the context provider, and from there try passing it to your custom hook, e.g const {editState, editActions} = useProtocolEdit(context). Also easier to test this way.

Comment: I had thought about passing down the context as props but wasn't sure if that was best practice or not. Thanks for clearing it up for me and for helping me understand hooks not being part of the component tree.